# When modyfing content inside a submodule, can I push it to my own repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-push, git-remote

I have a repository where I make use of a library that is available on GitHub.

I added that library as a submodule and I made some modifications to it.
Is it possible that I can now push the commits of the submodule to my own repository?
`git push` inside the submodule tries to push to the library's GitHub where I have no access to write.

Comment: One option is to fork the library on GitHub, and include that as your submodule.  You would then have full permissions to push changes to your fork when required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/849308/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+multiple+remotes